# How to query CSV file from mysql?

Tags: mysql, csv

How to query csv file using mysql? i have a .csv file and i want to query it so that i could get distinct record value from csv file.

Thanks
Yugal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You need to import it into mySQL. mySQL's command for that is [`LOAD DATA INFILE`.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Pekka: is there any other way to import only distinct record from csv file by mysql query?

Comment: @yugal I don't think so, no. I think the best way is still to import the whole file into a temporary table, then remove all the unwanted records

Answer (score 1):

You need to load it into MySQL table first. Then query as usual.

Alternatively you can try experimenting with [CSV storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html).